# How to use bus.bus to connect python and js?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

please give some advise about the bus.bus mechanism. I want that after calling the python function of the model, another function is called on the client side, also i want to call js function on every active user.
for example:

.py

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def my_func(self):
        #do_stuff
        self.env['bus.bus']._sendone(...)  # or something like this
```

.js

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        // here i wanna connect event to function test()  
    }

    test() {
        console.log('works');
    }
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update js template from server side in odoo15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76743598/how-to-update-js-template-from-server-side-in-odoo15)

Comment: I think so, I asked this question because maybe someone has worked with it and will provide short examples of how it can be implemented. I haven't marked your question yet, because I'm doing research with this mechanism, if I succeed, I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after some time of research, I found a solution how to implement such a mechanism.
first i tried to create my own channel for bus.bus but it didn't work for me so i went a trickier way.
I use the already existing activity_updated channel and send a notification to it with the required parameter that will mark my activity.
so, here is my code:

*.py

here i can send signal to all partners i need in any place i want.

update_counters - is a parameter to mark just my actions and do not run any another

```
self.env['bus.bus']._sendmany([
    [i, 'mail.activity/updated', {'update_counters': True}] for i in self.partner_ids
])
```

*.js

```
export class AppsBar extends Component {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        Component.env.bus.on('activity_updated', this, this.update_counters);
        this.my_counter = 0;
        this.update_counters();
    }
    
    async update_counters(data) {
        var do_this = false;
        if (data === undefined) {
            do_this = true;
        } else if (typeof data == "object") {
            if ('update_counters' in data) {
                do_this = true;
            }
        }
        if (do_this) {
            var rpc = require('web.rpc');
            var rpc_data = await rpc.query({
                model: 'res.users',
                method: 'get_counters',
                args: [[]],
            });
            this.my_counter= rpc_data['my_counter'];
            this.render()
        }
    }
}
```

`Component.env.bus.on('activity_updated', this, this.update_counters);` - this is my subscription to signal